# How to access array objects inside a Function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in javascript, I have a written a javascript program for snakes and ladders using array objects, but i'm not able to understand how to call the variable snake_pos with its start and end position. Here is the code:

```js
var player_pos = 4;
var dice_value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

function dice() {
  player_pos = player_pos + dice_value;
}
dice();

var last_pos = 25;

function game_rule() {
  if (player_pos >= last_pos)

  {
    alert("won the game");
  }
}

game_rule();

function snake() {
  var snake_pos = [{
      start_pos: 11,
      end_pos: 4
    },
    {
      start_pos: 20,
      end_pos: 7
    },
    {
      start_pos: 24,
      end_pos: 3
    }
  ]
}

console.log(player_pos);
console.log(dice_value);
console.log(snake_pos);
```

Comment: did you try on google .

Comment: First: you never called snake function. Second snake_pos is a variable inside function scope and you cannot access it from outside the function. The easiest solution would be to remove `var` from snake_pos declaration, but working on global variables should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `return` your variable `snake_pos` to use it outside the function. After that you can call the items in the `array` and `object`, take a look at this example:

```js
function snake(){
  // return the variable to use it outside the function
  return snake_pos = [
    {start_pos:11, end_pos:4},
    {start_pos:20, end_pos:7},
    {start_pos:24, end_pos:3}
  ]
}

//store the returned value in a variable
snake_pos = snake();

//log the first array item start_pos
console.log(snake_pos[0].start_pos);

//log the second array item start_pos
console.log(snake_pos[1].start_pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare `snake_pos` before in the same scope in which you're trying to access it:

```js
var player_pos = 4;
var dice_value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

// declare it here
var snake_pos = [{
    start_pos: 11,
    end_pos: 4
  },
  {
    start_pos: 20,
    end_pos: 7
  },
  {
    start_pos: 24,
    end_pos: 3
  }
];

function dice() {
  player_pos = player_pos + dice_value;
}
dice();

var last_pos = 25;

function game_rule() {
  if (player_pos >= last_pos)

  {
    alert("won the game");
  }
}

game_rule();

function snake() {
  // It will be accessible here as well
}

console.log(player_pos);
console.log(dice_value);

// It will be accessible here
console.log(snake_pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code and try to understand how its work.

```js
// declear global variables here
         var player_pos = 4;
         var last_pos = 25;
         var dice_value = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
         // function to play dice add dice value
         function dice(){
          dice_value = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
          player_pos = player_pos + dice_value;
         }

        // we have snake positions in this, we check user on snake position or not we will do action accordingly        
        function snake(){
         var snake_pos = [
          {start_pos:11, end_pos:4},
          {start_pos:20, end_pos:7},
          {start_pos:24, end_pos:3}
          ];
          
          for(var i =0; i < snake_pos.length; i++) {
            if(snake_pos[i].start_pos == player_pos) {
              player_pos = snake_pos[i].end_pos;
            }
          }
         }
         // in this we define game rule, if user won we return true
         function game_rule(){
           if (player_pos >= last_pos)
           {
            alert("won the game");
            return true;
           } else {
            return false;
           }
         }
         // we play game until user won this game
         while(game_rule() != true) {
           console.log(player_pos);
           console.log(dice_value); 
           dice();
           snake();
         }
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Happy Coding !!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Snake() {
      this.snake_pos = [{
          start_pos: 11,
          end_pos: 4
        },
        {
          start_pos: 20,
          end_pos: 7
        },
        {
          start_pos: 24,
          end_pos: 3
        }
      ]
    }
    var snake = new Snake();
    console.log(snake.snake_pos[0].start_pos);
```

Check this: https://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/